# Toggle driving me crazy in responsive design

Tags: jquery, toggle, responsive-design

I'm a total beginner with jQuery and I am having a lot of trouble with a responsive website I'm designing. Their are 2 horizontal menus on the desktop site, when the screen size hits 657px and less I need the horizontal menus to become drop down menus.

I thought I had everything working until I realised that when the screen size was less than 657px and I opened and closed(toggled?) the drop down it would open and close in the larger sizes as well, which makes perfect sense but I have no idea how to stop it doing that, so basically what I need is that the drop-down that appears at sizes 657px and less toggles only, not the horizontal menus as well.

I tried adding a .show to the horizontal menus at >=657 to make sure it always showed, but that just caused the contents of drop down menus to show before they were pressed . I thought it must be impossible until I saw many websites that have done it perfectly (bostonglobe.com for instance).

I think this question is very similar but I really didn't understand the solution: [Jquery toggle on responsive site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879509/jquery-toggle-on-responsive-site)

my HTML (it's an arabic website)

```
        <button id="categories-dd" class="unactive-main"></button>
    <nav id="main-navigation">
        <ul id="menu">
            <li class="leaf" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="Main.html">الرئيسية</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf1" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="politics-html.html">سياسة</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf2" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="sports-html.html">رياضة</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf3" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="business-html.html">أعمال</a>
            </li> 
            <li class="leaf4" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="culture-html.html">ثقافة</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf5" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="opinion-html.html">رأي</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf6" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="tech-html.html">تكنلوجيا</a>
            </li> 
            <li class="leaf7" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="lifestyle-html.html">نمط الحياة</a>
            </li>
            <li class="leaf8" id="dd-mainnav">
                <a href="multimedia-html.html">فيديو</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--END: MAIN NAVIGATION-->

    <!--SECONDARY NAVIGATION-->
    <button id="countries-dd" class="unactive-sec">البلد</button>
    <nav id="secondary-navigation">
        <ul id="menu2">
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">الإمارات</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">عمان</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">اليمن</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">السعودية</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">البحرين</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="arab-news-html.html">قطر</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="khalij-html.html">الكويت</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="iraq-html.html">العراق</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="syria-html.html">سوريا</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="lebanon-html.html">لبنان</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="jordan-html.html">الأردن</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="palestine-html.html">فلسطين</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="egypt-html.html">مصر</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="sudan-html.html">السودان</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="libya-html.html">ليبيا</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="tunisia-html.html">تونس</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="algeria-html.html">الجزائر</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="morocco-html.html">المغرب</a>
            </li>
            <li class="subleaf">
                <a href="mauritania-html.html">موريتانيا</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <!--END: SECONDARY NAVIGATION-->
```

my jQuery(please don't laugh):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#countries-dd,#categories-dd').on('click', function(){
        $(this).next().toggle();
        });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#categories-dd').on('click',function(){
        $('#categories-dd').toggleClass('active-main');
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#countries-dd").on('click',function(){
        $("#countries-dd").toggleClass("active-sec");
        });
    });
    });


     $(window).resize(function() {   
        if($(window).width() > 657)
        {
             $('#main-navigation, #secondary-navigation').show();
        }

    });
```

Any help is greatly appreciated....thank you!

Comment: You don't need to nest those document.ready functions.  All functions defined within document.ready will be executed when that event fires.  It's much cleaner to put all your code into a single document.ready function.

Comment: multiple click events on the same element can also be combined into a single event.

Answer (score 0):

You have several elements with the same ID `dd-mainnav`. That's not allowed. Use multiple classes instead:

```
<li class="leaf7 dd-mainnav">
```

Once you do that (and rewrite your JS and CSS accordingly), add a test for the window's width inside the `click` handlers:

```
$('#categories-dd').on('click',function(){
    if ($(window).width > 657){
        $(this).toggleClass('active-main');
    }
});
```

But it might be easier to leave your JS as-is and just add new styles to your mobile stylesheet:

```
#categories-dd, #categories-dd.active-main {
    display: block; /* or whatever */
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply,, I applied your advice on the id's and classes...the problem is that the drop-down menu works fine at mobile sizes, but its effect is carried into the larger sizes when i expand the browser. i.e upon opening and closing the drop-down menu on the mobile size and expanding the view port to past 657 the horizontal menu has disappeared, if i then go back to the mobile size and open the drop down menu and then expand to past 657 the horizontal menu appears again. I changed the #categories-dd to block but still not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4J3qU/ I added this in case it makes it easier to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, why so many document.ready functions...why not just the parent, with everything in it?  You don't need the nested readies.  Everything in ready is ready.  Also, you don't need two onclick functions.  In your selector, say

```
$('#categories-dd, #countries-dd').on
```

Also, I suggest using a parent selector.  For example, if the parent selector of #categories and #countries is - for the purpose of this explanation - #daddy .....

```
$('#daddy').on('click','#categories-dd, #countries-dd',function(){
    // code goes here  
});
```

Also, you have a LOT of the same id.  ID is a unique identifier.  use multiple classes if need be but the ID should be UNIQUE per item.

e.g.

```
<a class="this that theother someotherclass howevermanyclasses" id="uniquetome">see?</a>
```

I suggest in your on function, do the following:

```
     $('#menuINoLongerWant').toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help,, i took your advice and cleaned up the jQuery code...unfortunetly adding a parent selector to html  and ' $('#menuINoLongerWant').toggle();' to jQuery didn't stop the problem

Comment: No, it won't.  You should use .toggle() (which will toggle whether a given element is hidden or shown.)

Alternately you can use .hide() and .show() but .toggle() should work fine.